# Installation auto-triggers after every apt-get command

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, bash, java

I was trying to install ElasticSearch onto my system using the following script : https://gist.github.com/sachinkamath/b42861f4f6216e62ea37

However, the installation was not successful due to a curl error and I had to interrupt it before it could exit clean. Now, everytime I run an `apt-get` command, I am prompted to install the oracle-java-installer, which looks something like this :

[image: bash screenshot]

I want to get rid of this. I tried removing the corresponding repositories from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and also tried removing the repositories from `sources.list` and running `sudo apt-get upgrade` but that didn't solve the issue. What am I doing wrong here? How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the package(s) partially installed. 
Do this

```
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java8-installer
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/java
```